# ClickOnce is not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: clickonce

My [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment used to work perfectly, but it stopped working in Internet Explorer 9. It only displays the *Desktop.application* XML file. It still works in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), etc.

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, usually it works fine. However, depending on settings and the environment you can have such an issue.

- It may be wrong or missing MIME types on the server. See for example *[ClickOnce on Apache](http://software.clempaul.me.uk/articles/clickonce/)*.
- Specific Internet Explorer settings (for example, show content based on content), so try to reset all to default
- Corrupted/missing .NET framework 2.0

Also, please see these posts:

- *[Troubleshooting Specific Errors in ClickOnce Deployments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx)* (MSDN)
- *[Problems with ClickOnce deployment and IE9](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/53172aaf-1d30-43c8-8d52-7564b9ed1b7c)* (MSDN)
- *[ClickOnce is displaying the '.application' file as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481986)* (Stack Overflow)

Comment: How do I set the MIME types on the server, if I don't manage the server. I just upload my files to a web hosting company.

Comment: Well if only IE opens it as XML file, it looks like missing/wrong MIME types is not the reason. However you can check it with your hosting provider and configure it. For IIS it is just parameters in web.config in you folder (static content - mime map). Also you can use a web debugging tool to check response header if it contains right mime type.

Answer (score 0):

Does it use a .NET control? This solved my issue:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6c7eb28-28b3-4e07-aa11-40145a997271/object-tag-loading-a-net-control-works-in-ie8-red-x-in-ie9?forum=ieextensiondevelopment