# Is Microsoft ClickOnce compatible with IE11?

Tags: .net, clickonce, internet-explorer-11

We have a .Net app that is installed on a user's local machine with Microsoft ClickOnce via their browser.

Users have recently reported issues with the .Net app after upgrading to IE11.

Is Microsoft ClickOnce compatible with IE11? Will the installs complete successfully?

Comment: ClickOnce works with IE11.  Just remember that there are *four* flavors of IE11.  As to your question about installs completing successfully - that's entirely up to you and your client.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163411/clickonce-is-not-working-in-internet-explorer-9?